# Make a row or column of a matrix all zero's [Julia]

Tags: julia

I want to make all values in a `row` or `column` of a `Matrix` zero's (`Float64` in this case) without resorting to a manual for loop.

`fill!` and `zero` work on the entire matrix, but not on an individual column or row (at least my attempts have failed... ie., `fill!(tester[:,1],0.0)` doesn't work.

Here is an example of the manual method

```
tester = [[22.2 33.3  44.4]; [44.4  55.5 66.6]; [77.7 88.8 99.9] ]

for i = 1:size(tester,1)
    tester[i,1] = 0.0
end
```

the output for the initialization and modification is

```
[22.2 33.3 44.4; 44.4 55.5 66.6; 77.7 88.8 99.9]  <-- Initial matrix
[0.0 33.3 44.4; 0.0 55.5 66.6; 0.0 88.8 99.9]     <-- Correct change
```

A comprehension can probably be used to make the `for loop` look a little tidier, but that is just cosmetics. I am wondering if there is an actual function like `fill!` or `zero` that can be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use array indexing with `:` to select all the entries along the dimension you choose and `.=`.

```
julia> tester = [22.2 33.3 44.4; 44.4 55.5 66.6; 77.7 88.8 99.9];

julia> tester[:,1] .= 0.0;

julia> tester
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  33.3  44.4
 0.0  55.5  66.6
 0.0  88.8  99.9
```

For more about indexing an array, you might find it useful to read [the relevant manual entry.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/index.html#man-supported-index-types-1)

Comment: I always forget the "`.`". I tried it without the dot... I am too used to Fortran :S. This works as desired though.

Comment: I kinda guessed that actually :). This is still a useful question though, if not asked before.